# Hash to create Hex Color Codes from string (in bash)

Tags: bash, hash, hexidecimal

I am wanting to produce graphs of my server traffic using **rrdtool**, but it expects hex color codes for each line on the graph.

Since I am wanting to iterate over a varying bunch of domain data files, I would like to **generate these color codes programatically**.  I would also like them to remain consistent for a given domain data file - so I think a **hash of the domain name** would be a good method to use.  Problem is, I don't know where to begin.

Is there a simple algorithm that I can use in bash to hash strings (domain names) into **hex color codes**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about md5?

```
domain=example.com
color=#`echo -n $domain | md5 | cut -c1-6`
```

The resulting variable `$color` will be `#5ababd`

Comment: note the '-n' in the edit - although the hash works equally well without it, this ensures that the MD5 sum is based only on the domain name _without_ a trialing carriage return.

Comment: Do keep in mind that this will occasionally come up with bad colors (e.g, same as the background color).